# how to start xclock (or something else) to be displayed on my HDMI device on Raspbian console session?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display, xorg

I have a raspberry pi 2 and installed the Raspbian Version from 2015-05-05.

As "boot option" I chose "Console Text console..." because I don't want a full desktop.

I logged in from my remote PC via SSH (putty). I want to start Firefox but get the following error:

```
root@raspberry:~# firefox

(process:2425): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size =                                   = 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

If I try to start xclock I also get an error:

```
root@raspberry:~# xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

I want to start the programs on my display connected via HDMI.
Even if I do this directly on my raspberry console it doesn't work.

How can I tell my raspberry to display this programs on my via HDMI connected Display?

Comment: I've just noticed it's sort of implicit here that you don't have any GUI desktop running.  You cannot run a GUI app without a desktop.

Comment: What is showing on your HDMI display?

Comment: Hi Bex, the console session is showing on the HDMI display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the display number.  To find that:

```
> xauth list
localhost.localdomain/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  ea5bf
```

It's the number after the colon.  Then set:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Notice I included the colon.  You should now be able to launch `xclock` or

```
firefox &
```

You have to be logged in as the same user who opened the display, or else run that root/sudo, which in the case of a web browser is *a bad idea*.

Comment: if i try this i get: `root@raspberry:~# firefox &
[1] 2335
root@raspberry:~#
(process:2335): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :0.0`

Comment: Hmm -- works for me.  I've edited in how to make sure the display number is correct.

Comment: hm... okay maybe X is the problem. if i do `xauth list` i recive nothing...

Comment: @frupfrup Did you start X? Is it installed?

Comment: X musst be installed because with `startX` comand i get the "normal" Raspbian desktop. I also can leave this activ but i would like to start e.g. xclock directly from the console... or is this still impossible? - Sorry i am not an linux expert... :-/

Comment: X must be installed, AND running. `startx &` will get you the desktop session, or you can just run `/usr/bin/X &` for a root window without background image or anything. In either case, wait until the screen is setup and type `DISPLAY=:0 xclock`.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the fact that you did not have X running at all.  No, you cannot start normal GUI applications on the console -- they require X to provide the windowing system.  There are special graphical apps that can run on the console [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) but they are few in number.

Answer (score 1):

To start xWindows stuff over the ssh you need to add -X to the ssh command, so:

ssh -X ....

In putty it is a bit different - you need to enable X11 forwarding by following [this](https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY) procedure (for example :))

Comment: ok. Thx for this link. But i get the error mentioned in the comment before also if i type in "Firefox &" directly on console... i would even be happy if it would work on the console

Comment: @Bostjan ... can you copy the highlights of the article you reference into your answer - the page might go away some time in the future and that would leave your answer without a key component.

Comment: But the O.P. isn't trying to forward X (I think); s/he wants to start a GUI application *on the remote machine's display* after logging in via `ssh`.   X11 forwarding is when you want to run a GUI application from the remote machine and display it *on your local desktop*.  I can start xclock on another system with `X11Forwarding no` in  `sshd_config` and without using `-X`, as long as I set the `DISPLAY` variable correctly.  I can't promise it isn't something else to do with the sshd config, or the X server config, but this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run xclock from console with out startx 
try :
xinit xclock

NOTE: this is an alternative compromise :) But you need to run startx then you can run and X application(Gui Application).