# How to diagnose problem with OpenCV face tracking

Tags: camera, opencv

I am attemping to create the pan-tilt face tracker, using

- Raspberry Pi 2
- Raspian
- Regular Raspberry Pi Camera

from an article on the [Pimoroni site](http://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/electromechanical/building-a-pan-tilt-face-tracker), and when I run the python code I get about 20 lines of

> VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument

and ends with

```
(Video:3418) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

I honestly have no idea how to diagnose this at all

-------------UPDATE----------------------

After some helpful info in the comments I ran it under vnc and now a video windows pops up - however the

> VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument

error is still there, and a new error message of

```
Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0"
```

appears

There is still no servo movement.

-------------UPDATE----------------------
I am connecting using either Putty or TightVNC - I do not have the option of connecting a monitor to the pi at the moment

Comment: And you are running this from within an X session?

Comment: @WernerKvalemVesterås I'm using Putty (windows SSH) - should I have it hooked up to a monitor or remote in through VNC?

Comment: It may not solve the first error but that's definitely the issue with the second one.  Gtk is a GUI toolkit.  If you have a display connected with X running, you'll have to have to provide the display id ([see here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/32126/5538])).  That is probably a little more foolproof than VNC, at least until you know it is working.

Comment: Progress!  I tried it under vnc/LX Termainal, and while I still get the VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument warning, - instead of the (Video:3418) : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display error I get, well, see the updated question....

Comment: What happens if you put `DISPLAY=:0` before the command, like `DISPLAY=:0 python -m module.tool` as well as make sure you do *not* have XForwarding enabled?

Comment: Try running the program without sudo. I ran into similar problem while running a GUI program over VNC with sudo.

Comment: @dastaan - I just tried it without the sudo - no luck sadly

Comment: Try using x11vncserver instead of tightvncserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - it would seem that the open cv program doesn't work in either a shell or TightVNC - but it does work in a different vnc program - Ultra VNC in my case.  I reloaded the code and everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Check 
echo $DISPLAY
what is it showing?
is it showing the correct display?

Note before this try to be in x session
Do, startx for starting x server, open Lxterminal
and please post the output of echo $DISPLAY

it should show :0 as output.
else try export DISPLAY=":0"

and then run your program/application from lxterminal.

Answer (score -2):

close the putty and work on vnc terminal 
work on one of them only

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please explain how this is supposed to be relevant to the question?